# How to remove empty row from grid view in asp.net

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview

From my gridview, an extra row added. this issue comes when using google chrome & microsoft edge browser but when using mozilla, this issue not found.

[image]

From the above image, see the last row added(automatically) after pagination. how to fix this issue in asp.net c#

Grid design is given below,

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridQuoteSearch" runat="server" SelectedRowStyle-BackColor="Blue" AllowPaging="true"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" PageSize="100"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="1250px" Font-Names="Arial" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
    HeaderStyle-Height="25px" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#316AC5" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#8080FF"
    BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" GridLines="Both" HorizontalAlign="Left"
    Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="Small" EmptyDataText="No US Bank Invoice Search Results Found!" CaptionAlign="Top"
>
    <PagerSettings Mode="NumericFirstLast" FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#99FAFF"></SelectedRowStyle>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="DataGridFixedHeader" BackColor="#316AC5" BorderColor="#8080FF" Font-Size="13px" ForeColor="#FFFFFF" HorizontalAlign="Left"></HeaderStyle>
    <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" />
    <EmptyDataRowStyle Font-Bold="True" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="#FF66FF" Height="250px" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
    <Columns>
    <%-- 
    <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" ItemStyle-CssClass="GridItem">
        <ItemTemplate><%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %></ItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" CssClass="GridItem"></ItemStyle>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    --%>
    <%--
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Sl No" DataField="ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Id">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    --%>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Mode" DataField="Mode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="Mode">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Shipper Name" DataField="ShipperName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="ShipperName">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Buyer ID" DataField="BuyerID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="BuyerID">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Carrier Name" DataField="CarrierName" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="CarrierName">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Carrier ID (SCAC)" DataField="CarrierID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" SortExpression="CarrierID">
        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" Font-Bold="false" Width="5%"></ItemStyle>
        <HeaderStyle></HeaderStyle>
    </asp:BoundField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

binding grid code is given below

```
private void BindGrid()
{
    DataTable table = (DataTable)Session["table"];
    gridQuoteSearch.DataSource = table;
    gridQuoteSearch.DataBind();
}

protected void OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    gridQuoteSearch.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.BindGrid();
}
```

Comment: At a guess, that could be the footer row. The `ShowFooter` property defaults to `false`, but if you've applied a default control skin, that could be overriding it.

Comment: @RichardDeeming , Thank you for the response, but this issue in chrome & edge browser. When using mozilla, this issue not found.

Comment: Then there's something else going on that you haven't shown - probably in either your CSS or Javascript.